# how to convert text value into 24 hour datetime object c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

I have a textbox in my WPF application in which i'm getting time in 24 hour format. What I  want is, if my textbox's time is less than current time then *IF condition* should be true but its not working...

e.g:

```
txtdeparturetime.Text = 00:10

time == 00:31// time==>(object) here current time

if(txtdeparturetime.Text < time) // than this should work
```

Below is my code.

```
DateTime time = new DateTime();

DateTime deptime = DateTime.Parse(txtdeparturetime.Text);//converting textbox value into date object

if ((TimeSpan.Compare(deptime.TimeOfDay, time.TimeOfDay)) == -1)
{
    //some code here          
}
```

Comment: Your code _won't_ even compile. Can you please create a [MCVE] and be more clear about your it?

Comment: @SonerGönül check i edit my Questioni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime t2 = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
        int i = DateTime.Compare(t1, t2);

        if (i < 1)
        {

        }

    }
```

Now, The variable *i* **will be less than Zero** if *t1* is less than *t2*.

If t1 is equals t2 the result is **Zero**.

Finally, if *t1* is bigger than *t2* the result will be bigger than **Zero**.

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare to `DateTime.Now` instead of `new DateTime()` and can use a simple `<` comparison operator.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;    
DateTime deptime = DateTime.Parse(txtdeparturetime.Text);

if (deptime.TimeOfDay < now.TimeOfDay)
{
     //some code here          
}
```

here is a working example with text set by a constant instead of a text field.

```
 public static void test1()
 {
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string timetext = "2017-02-04 12:16PM";
    DateTime deptime = DateTime.Parse(timetext);
    Console.WriteLine("text time="+timetext);
    if (deptime.TimeOfDay < now.TimeOfDay)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("time is less than now");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("End");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Error 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex' does not contain a definition for 'TimeOfDay' and no extension method 'TimeOfDay' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: can you paste that code? looks that you're calling `TimeOfDay` on a `Regex` object instead of a `DateTime` object